# Vue.js - change nested property by passing a parameter in v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, v-model

I've got an array 'products' displayed with v-for. For each product there is a button to add a product to an object 'order'. Object 'order' looks like

```
order: {
  products: [{
    quantity: 0,
    otherProperties
  }]
}
```

When clicked a second time on that button, I want to increase the quantity with 1.

So, in Vuex where I pass the clicked object:

```
increaseQuantity(state, product){
  state.order.products.find((orderProduct)=>{
    return product.id === orderProduct.id
  }).quantity++;
```

So far so good. I can see the quantity increase in the chrome developer tool.

Now the tricky thing, and I've no idea how to accomplish this, although it sounds easy: I want to show the quantity of each product in an input field next to the button. Problem is that I need the selected product in the v-model like this:

```
<div v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
  <input v-model="order.products.find((orderProduct)=>{
    return product.id === orderProduct.id
  }).quantity" />
</div>
```

The moment the product is added to the 'order' object, the quantity value of 0 is displayed in the input field, so the DOM updated. But nothing changes in the DOM when the quantity changes. However, the quantity did change in the vuex store.

Is there a way to solve this? I tried with :value instead of v-model, but same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`this.$set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays) to make that change reactive :

```
increaseQuantity(state, product){
  let index= state.order.products.findIndex((orderProduct)=>{
    return product.id === orderProduct.id
  })
state.order.products.quantity++;
this.$set(state.order.products,index,state.order.products[index])

}
```

Comment: Vue.set was indeed what I needed, thank you! Don't now why I never thought of this

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have mutated the store in a non-reactive way; that means **Vue** doesn't track your changes, so the DOM is not updated.

I reworked your code a bit in the following snippet:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    products: [
      {
        id: 1,
        quantity: 0
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        quantity: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_PRODUCT(state, { id: productId, amount }) {
      const product = state.products.find(({ id }) => id === productId)
      if (product) {
        if (!product.hasOwnProperty('order')) {
          // this is the way to set data in a reactive-way
          Vue.set(product, 'order', true)
        } else {
          product.quantity = Number(amount)
        }
      }
    }
  },
  actions: {
    addProduct({ commit }, data) {
      commit('ADD_PRODUCT', data)
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getProducts: ({ products }) => products,
    getOrdered: ({ products }) => {
      return products.filter(product => {
        return product.hasOwnProperty('order') ? product : false
      })
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('Product', {
  props: ['product'],
  computed: {
    buttonText() {
      if (!this.product.order) {
        return 'ADD TO ORDER'
      } else {
        return 'SET ORDERED QUANTITY'
      }
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      amount: 0
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>Product: {{ product.id }}, {{ product.quantity }}
      <button @click="addToOrder(product.id, amount)">{{ buttonText }}</button>
      <input
        v-if="product.order"
        type="number"
        v-model="amount"
        min="0"
        @input="addToOrder(product.id, amount)"
      >
    </div>`,
  methods: {
    addToOrder(id, amount) {
      this.$store.dispatch('addProduct', { id, amount })
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('Ordered', {
  props: ['product'],
  template: `
    <div>
      Product {{ product.id }} quantity: {{ product.quantity }}
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  computed: {
    products() {
      return this.$store.getters.getProducts
    },
    ordered() {
      return this.$store.getters.getOrdered
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.5.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <h3>PRODUCT LIST</h3>
    <product
      v-for="product in products"
      :key="product.id"
      :product="product"
    />
  </div>
  <hr />
  <h3>ORDERED LIST</h3>
  <ordered
    v-for="product in ordered"
    :key="`ordered-${ product.id }`"
    :product="product"
  />
</div>
```

The idea is that I only change the products' `order` attribute to keep track of what the full order is. I also created a `getter` that filters the products that are ordered (so if I'd need only those at some point, I just call that `getter`).

This is a simple way:

- you can set the ordered amount by merely using the input field
- there's only one array for all the products
- the products keep track of their own state (ordered property and amount)

And some more information on **Vue**'s reactivity: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Wow thanks for the effort! Vue.set was indeed what I needed. Also used :value instead of v-model because I was binding to a method. state.order.products.push(Object.assign({}, product)) worked too instead of Vue.set